# Connecting OLAP4j to Analysis Server

Tags: sql, ssas, olap

I have been having trouble connecting programmatically to my MSSAS with OLAP4J

I have confirmed that the server works by connecting with excel

"jdbc:xmla:SERVER=http://(MyVM).cloudapp.net;Catalog = (MyCatalog)", "username", "password");

but get timeouts when querying

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.olap4j.OlapException: This connection encountered an exception while executing a query.
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.getList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:96)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.size(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:116)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.getOlapDatabase(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:451)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.getOlapCatalog(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:501)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.getCatalog(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:496)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jStatement.executeOlapQuery(XmlaOlap4jStatement.java:291)
    at test.main(test.java:20)
Caused by: org.olap4j.OlapException: This connection encountered an exception while executing a query.
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaHelper.createException(XmlaHelper.java:43)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.executeMetadataRequest(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:878)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.getMetadata(XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.java:137)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.getMetadata(XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.java:67)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseProperties(XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.java:1044)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.makeConnectionPropertyList(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:324)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.generateRequest(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:1037)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.populateList(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:849)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.populateList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:136)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.getList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:90)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jProxyException: This proxy encountered an exception while processing the query.
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.getResponse(XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.java:181)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jAbstractHttpProxy.get(XmlaOlap4jAbstractHttpProxy.java:181)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.get(XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.java:42)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.executeMetadataRequest(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:876)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.getResponse(XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.java:133)
    ... 17 more
```

This is on OLAP4J 1.2.0

With the path to msmdpump i get this error

jdbc:xmla:SERVER=http:/http://(MyVM).cloudapp.net/OLAP/msmdpump.dll;Catalog = "(MyCatalog)", "Username", "password"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.olap4j.OlapException: This connection encountered an exception while executing a query.
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.getList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:96)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.size(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:116)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.getOlapDatabase(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:451)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.getOlapCatalog(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:501)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.getCatalog(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:496)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jStatement.executeOlapQuery(XmlaOlap4jStatement.java:291)
    at test.main(test.java:20)
Caused by: org.olap4j.OlapException: This connection encountered an exception while executing a query.
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaHelper.createException(XmlaHelper.java:43)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.executeMetadataRequest(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:878)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.getMetadata(XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.java:137)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.getMetadata(XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.java:67)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseProperties(XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.java:1044)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.makeConnectionPropertyList(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:324)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.generateRequest(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:1037)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.populateList(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:849)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.populateList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:136)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.getList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:90)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jProxyException: This proxy encountered an exception while processing the query.
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.getResponse(XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.java:181)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jAbstractHttpProxy.get(XmlaOlap4jAbstractHttpProxy.java:181)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.get(XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.java:42)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.executeMetadataRequest(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:876)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.getResponse(XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.java:133)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server URL isn't quite right. It usually points to a file called MSMDPUMP.dll that you deploy on your IIS server.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx) for a few hints.

Comment: i have tried that previously, and in sql server i could connect to my IIS and it was Displaying the analysis server however i still get a timeout error